# Rails flash.now AJAX strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am using `flash.now[:success] = ...` to display a message after a form is submitted. Everything is working fine, except when I navigate away from the page, and then come back, the flash message *briefly* shows up and then automatically disappears (it is only visible for a fraction of a second). What is causing this?

Controller

```
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @foo.save
      format.html { redirect_to ... }
      format.js { flash.now[:success] = 'Foo was created successfully.' }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could it be Turbolinks?

Comment: can you share the code you used to display flash message